# Half screen div doesn't expand to its full width

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website, and for some reason, at full screen the footer expands to its full width, but when I reduce the screen size, there's a random white block that appears on the bottom right. Any ideas? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW3P0.png

HTML:

```
<div id="footer-container">
        <footer>
             <?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#footer-container {
      min-width: 100%;
      background: #41038e;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
footer {
     width: 960px;
     height: 140px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding-top: 10px; 
}
```

Here's the website: http://thecupertinoflorist.com/index.php

Comment: Looks fine on Firefox 21.0

Comment: I opened it in Aurora and Chrome and both appear to have the problem.

Comment: It looks like your header might be expanding too far to the right.

Comment: It should be `.footer` instead of `footer`. But that won't fix your problem (although it looks okay here too (Firefox))

Comment: @showdev how do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem using the following CSS changes:
(like Serlite's answer)

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 1200px; /* ADDED. keeps site from shrinking below 1200px wide */
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can probably remove some other definitions:

```
div#header-inner {
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    /*width: 1200px; REMOVED */
    z-index: 1;
}    

.navbar {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*width: 1200px; REMOVED */
}    

.navbar-inner {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #41038E;
    border: medium none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    /*width: 1200px; REMOVED */
}    

div#logo {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    /*width: 1200px; REMOVED */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...well, one way you could address this is to set the min-width of your body to be equal to the widest element on the page with a set width (right now, it's set to 960px). In this case, this would be your "#header-inner", which is 1200px in width. So your body would end up looking like this in styles.css:

```
body {
    font-family: OpenSansRegular;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

This definitely isn't the only way to address your issue, but I hope it does help you out in some way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Change the widh of id in your css

```
div#footer-container{width:1200px;}
```